# SoX on 64-bit Windows 7 laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit

I am not able to start the program. I understand i have to use it as a prompt command to open but what do i need to write down there in order to work? This is what i type in cmd and select it and typed in sox.exe infile.wav outfile.mp3 or only sox.exe but it is not recognised as a program on my laptop. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

SoX.exe is an installer. You want to double-click the .exe file, install it, <strike>and then perform whatever commands you want by typing, for example, `sox infile.wav outfile.mp3` in cmd. ([source](http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse373/11sp/homework/1/soxusage.txt))</strike>

Edit: Nevermind! Sox installs itself in the Programs File folder (`C:\Program Files\sox-[version]` on my computer), and as a desktop shortcut, and must be run as a .exe file like you said. The easiest way to do this is to **click-and drag the  `sox.exe` desktop shortcut into your cmd window**, then append your other arguments (`infile.wav outfile.mp3` etc). So the whole command would look like `"C:\Users\[user]\Desktop\sox.exe.lnk" infile.wav outfile.mp3`.

If your installer didn't make a shortcut, **navigate to the sox directory, and click-and drag `sox.exe` into your cmd window**, then append arguments. Ex: `"C:\Program Files\sox.exe" infile.wav outfile.mp3`

---

Edit: Aaaand as for how to actually use SoX for what you want... SoX does have a pitch-shift command, [according to the documentation page](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html):

> `pitch [−q] shift [segment [search [overlap]]]`
>   Change the audio pitch (but not tempo).
>   shift gives the pitch shift as positive or negative ‘cents’ (i.e. 100ths of a semitone).

I don't, however, know how to convert semitones and Hz, <strike>or actually pretty much anything musical</strike>.

Unless you need a commandline solution (like if you want to make a script), **it'd probably be easier to use [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)'s `Effect > Change Pitch` menu, which has Hz options and is really easy to use.**

Comment: I did, problem is when i double click sox.exe the cmd window appears and dissapears almost simultaneously. Even when i first open cmd and then type in sox.exe it doesn't find the file.

Comment: Once you've double-clicked the executable, the program should be installed. Does the sox command work (as I wrote in the answer)?

Comment: Nope, cmd window closes within a second after it opens. I read about same problem an other user has and they suggested he started with cmd and type in further from there to open the program. Don't know what else to type then what i listed above as commands, nothing seem to work whaterver version i choose of sox.

Comment: To execute a command, you should only have to type its name, like "sox (whatever)" instead of "sox.exe (whatever)"; what is the result of putting something likt that in cmd?

Comment: Ok, sox only then. The result is an other window that says it is not a valid win32 application. Thanks for helping me so far, i appreciate it.

Comment: Tried it out in Windows, and I was wrong! Does my edited answer work for you?

Comment: There is certainly something going on. There is a lot of text in the cmd now. Maybe i should mention what i mainly want to do with SoX. I like to convert all my my CD's, wav, flac, mp3 files that are recorded in the common 440hz and pitch them down to 432hz. i hope you understand. I read this could be done with SoX.

Comment: I'm not sure if this ought to be a separate SU question or not. But in any case, I edited my answer accordingly.